# No puedo hacer que el resultado de csv salga en una misma linea a la izquierda por igual

Tags: python-3.x, csv

No puedo hacer que el resultado del botón buscar libro de la ventana de resultado, me salga todo a la izquierda así:

Libro: cien años de soledad

Editorial: librio

Autor: mario

Paginas: 422

Y me sale así:

Libro: cien años de soledad

```
 Editorial: librio

      Autor: mario

                Paginas: 422
```

Aquí también la foto https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPbP8.png
Ya intente poniendo place(x=120, y=420) y poniendo los Label uno debajo de otro, pero no se como ponerlos, también intente cambiando la variable y separando para ponerlo uno encima del otro. Acá dejo el código:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import csv

biblioteca = tk.Tk()
biblioteca.config(width=300, height=270)
biblioteca.title("Biblioteca")
texto_principal = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Colocar Nuevo Libro")
texto_principal.place(x=70, y=20)

texto = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nombre de libro: ")
texto.place(x=10, y=50)
entry = ttk.Entry()
entry.place(x=140, y=50)
texto1 = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nombre de editorial: ")
texto1.place(x=10, y=80)
entry1 = ttk.Entry()
entry1.place(x=140, y=80)
texto2 = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nombre del autor: ")
texto2.place(x=10, y=110)
entry2 = ttk.Entry()
entry2.place(x=140, y=110)
texto3 = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Número de paginas: ")
texto3.place(x=10, y=140)
entry3 = ttk.Entry()
entry3.place(x=140, y=140)
####################### ETIQUETAS NUEVAS ######################
Label_info_libro = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Informacion del libro: ")
Label_info_libro .place(x= 10, y= 200)
Label_mostrar_info_libro = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Resultado", anchor = "w")
Label_mostrar_info_libro.place(x= 10, y= 220)
######################## ETIQUETAS NUEVAS ######################

def libro():
    libro_nombre = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Libro: " + entry.get())
    libro_nombre.place(x=120, y=200)
    libro_editorial = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Editorial: " + entry1.get())
    libro_editorial.place(x=120, y=215)
    libro_autor = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Autor: " + entry2.get())
    libro_autor.place(x=120, y=230)
    libro_paginas = tk.Label(biblioteca, text = "Nº de Paginas: " + entry3.get())
    libro_paginas.place(x=120, y=245)
    
###################### SENTENCIAS MEJORADAS #######################
    
    nombre_libro = entry.get()
    editorial_libro = entry1.get()
    autor_libro = entry2.get()
    paginas_libro = entry3.get()

    guardado = "libro1.txt"
    with open(guardado, 'a') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        informacion_libro = (nombre_libro, editorial_libro, autor_libro, paginas_libro)
        csvwriter.writerow( informacion_libro )
##################### SENTENCIAS MEJORADAS #########################

##################### FUNCIONES NUEVAS ###############################

def Cargar_txt():
    lista_libros = []              # lista para almacenar la info del archivo
    nombre_archivo = "libro1.txt"  # variable con el nombre del archivo txt

    archivo_txt = open( nombre_archivo, "r")        # se abre el archivo txt
    # print(archivo_txt)
    # print("readlines:",archivo_txt.readlines())
    for fila in archivo_txt.readlines():            # se accede a cada linea del  archivo por iteracion
        # print("iterador for:",libro)                  
        if fila != "\n" and fila != "":               
            fila = fila.strip().split(",")    # se elimina el caracter "\n" y se  separarn los datos en base a las comas
            # print("info libro:",info_libro)
            lista_libros.append(fila )         # se agrega la info del libro a la lista de los libros
            # print("lista libros:",lista_libros)                                 
    archivo_txt.seek(0)                          # devuelve el cursor del texto al inicio del archivo
    # print(lista_libros)
    archivo_txt.close() 
    return lista_libros


def Buscar_autor():
# cargar datos de los libros
    lista_libros = Cargar_txt()
    print("recibida de cargar txt:",lista_libros)
# realizar busqueda del libro
    datos_libro = ""
    autor_consultado = Entry_autor_buscado.get()
    print("entry de autor:",autor_consultado)
    for info_libro in lista_libros:
        print("fila:",info_libro)
        if autor_consultado  == info_libro[0]:
            Label_mostrar_info_libro["text"] = resumen = "Libro: {}\nEditorial: {}\nAutor: {}\nPaginas: {}".format( *info_libro)
            break
# mostrar los datos del libro en el label

###########################  FUNCIONES NUEVAS  ########################

boton = tk.Button(biblioteca, text = "Guardar", command = libro)
boton.place(x=140, y=170)

####################### BOTON NUEVO #################################
boton_buscar_libro = tk.Button(biblioteca, text = "Buscar Libro", command = Buscar_autor)
boton_buscar_libro.place(x=200, y=170)
############################ BOTON NUEVO ############################

############################ ENTRY DE AUTOR #########################
Entry_autor_buscado = ttk.Entry()
Entry_autor_buscado .place(x=10, y=170)
############################ ENTRY DE AUTOR #########################

biblioteca.mainloop()
```

Solo me falta esto para acabar el libro de python.

Comment: Por default, las lineas de un label estan centradas. Para cambiar ese comportamiento, usa el parametro justify (en este caso, agrega al label justify="left" para que el texto se alinee a la izquierda)

Comment: gracias funciono.

Comment: De nada nekordemon c:

Comment: cierra la pregunta

Comment: como se cierra una pregunta